# Given a sample space of three events and the probability of two pairs of events, find the probability of each individual event

Tags: probability

> Let $S = \{\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3\}$ be the sample space of an
>   experiment. If $P(\{\omega_1,\omega_2\})=0.5$ and
>   $P(\{\omega_1,\omega_3\})=0.7$, find $P(\{\omega_1\})$,
>   $P(\{\omega_2\})$, and $P(\{\omega_3\})$.

I know that $P(\{\omega_1,\omega_2\})=P(\omega_1)+P(\omega_2)=0.5$, so I tried using the theorem below:$$P(\omega_1 \cup \omega_2)=P(\omega_1)+P(\omega_2)-P(\omega_1\omega_2)$$
Since we know $P(\omega_1)+P(\omega_2)=0.5$, this is equivalent to
$$P(\omega_1 \cup \omega_2)=0.5-P(\omega_1\omega_2)$$
Using the same logic, I also determined that
$$P(\omega_1 \cup \omega_3)=0.7-P(\omega_1\omega_3)$$
But I don't know what I could do at this point to answer the question. Maybe I am using the wrong approach?

Comment: You only have enough information to solve if the three subsets are mutually exclusive and exhaustive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assume the three outcomes are exclusive and they are the only possibilities.  In that case, you simply need to solve a linear system of three equations in three unknowns,

Let $P_k=P(\omega_k)$.  The equations are:

$P_1+P_2=.5$, $P_1+P_3=.7$, and $P_1+P_2+P_3=1$.

With solution $P_1=.2$, $P_2=.3$, and $P_3=.5$.

Comment: And here I spent a good 15 minutes trying to solve the problem before giving up and typing up a comment saying there wasn't enough information to solve the problem...I should have realized $\mathbb P(\{\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3\})=1$ was sufficient. Nicely done.